# How to use A-Frame to build a multi-scene VR game?

Tags: aframe, webvr

If I want to build a game with several scenes, how can I realize this with A-Frame? Is it feasible to wrap the elements in an empty entity with different page id?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the scene with JS:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1023

A working example is here:
https://curious-electric.com/w/experiments/aframe/scene-switch/

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, I have successfully realized the scene switch right now, but also I have a concern. Since we realize it by controlling the visible attribute, does it mean the browser will load all elements in different scenes at one time? Will this possibly lead to stuck of browsing?

Comment: Yes, it does. Hence I wouldn't make these scenes too large.
Also keep in mind that you need this scene switching only when you need to stay in VR mode. In any other case you can simply load another page.
Also, I hear that link traversal will bei in 0.6, so this may give us a better approach.